# Citrus Payment Gateway Android integration

Tags: android, citrus-pay, citrus-android-sdk

I have to integrate Citrus Payment gateway into my android app, Any help will be appreciated.
[website here](http://www.citruspay.com/citrus-checkout.html)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/index.html#/androidsdk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Citrus has provided with some really simplified developer's guide for efficient technical integration. Lets walk through the sample Net banking integration.Remaining steps can be found over [The Citrus Developer's Guide](http://www.citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/index.html#/androidintegration).

- Make sure that you have the following parameters from Citrus.([How to get following parameters](http://www.citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/index.html#/overview))

> 1. Secret Key
> 2. Access Key
> 3. SignIn Key
> 4. SignIn Secret
> 5. SignUp Key
> 6. SignUp Secret

- Download the kit from - Example and Citruslibrary. Add Citruslibrary as a dependency to Example. From Github.

  git clone https://github.com/citruspay/open-android-v2.git
- Have a look at the init function. You can set the keys with citrus config.

  ```
  private void init() 
   {
        Config citrus = new Config();
        citrus.setEnv("sandbox"); //replace it with production when you are ready
        citrus.setupSignupId("merchant-signup");
        citrus.setupSignupSecret("3e2288d3a1a3f59ef6f93373884d2ca1");
        citrus.setSigninId("merchant-wallet");
        citrus.setSigninSecret("c40798d3c12114b5bb19f2051d9ed181");
   }
  ```
- Get the bill from your server.Collect user details.Call the charge API.

  ```
     private void cardpay(String bill_string) 
    {
        Bill bill = new Bill(bill_string);
        Card card = new Card("4111111111111111", "11", "21", "000", "Tony Stark", "debit");
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(customer);
        PG paymentgateway = new PG(card, bill, userDetails);
        paymentgateway.charge(new Callback() 
            {
                   @Override
                   public void onTaskexecuted(String success, String error) 
                   {
                         processresponse(success, error);
                   }
            }
        });
     }
  ```
- Calling charge with Netbanking

  ```
   private void bankpay(String bill_string)
  {
    Bill bill = new Bill(bill_string);
    Bank netbank = new Bank("CID002");
    UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(customer);
    PG paymentgateway = new PG(netbank, bill, userDetails);
    paymentgateway.charge(new Callback()
        {
             @Override
             public void onTaskexecuted(String success, String error) 
                 {
                      processresponse(success, error);
                 }
        });
     }
  ```

Comment: These keys are provided by Citrus. Found on Citrus merchant panel. :) http://www.citruspay.com/

Comment: @Daenarys I can see very less options in net banking bank options. Is it because of sandbox environment? Also bill_string will be generated from our server?

Comment: 1) Sandbox test env has less options, all others will be covered up on production env.
2) Bill string will be generated at your server.

Comment: i am getting an exception, can anyone help me ?  :FileNotFoundException: https://sandbox.citruspay.com/

Comment: You can ask a new question for your problem. So that experts can get more clarity on the problem you are facing.

Comment: @NagamaInamdar great!